# Propagation of uncertainty/standard deviations in biological experiments

Tags: r, standard-deviation, biostatistics, error-propagation

I am trying to work out how to propagate standard deviations in a biological experiment, but I have some difficulties.

I have the following (semi)fictitious data originating from an image analysis resulting in optical density (OD) measurements:

```
ds <- data.frame(
    Sample = c(rep(seq(1,6),2)),
    Control.OD = c(7000, 7100, 5600, 5200, 5900, 7000, 
                   8100, 7700, 6100, 5500, 6600, 7500), 
    Target.OD  = c(1000,  330,   35, 9300, 5570, 8700, 
                   1300,  400,   62, 9100, 5817, 9000),
    Group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)

print(ds)

   Sample Control.OD Target.OD Group
1       1       7000      1000     1
2       2       7100       330     1
3       3       5600        35     1
4       4       5200      9300     2
5       5       5900      5570     2
6       6       7000      8700     2
7       1       8100      1300     1
8       2       7700       400     1
9       3       6100        62     1
10      4       5500      9100     2
11      5       6600      5817     2
12      6       7500      9000     2
```

The data represents duplicate measurements from one experiment with 6 biological samples from two different groups.

I do the following:

```
# Aggregate technical duplicates
ds.Agg <- aggregate(cbind(Control.OD, Target.OD) ~ Sample + Group, 
                    data = ds, mean)

# Rename columns for easier reading
names(ds.Agg)[names(ds.Agg)=="Control.OD"] <- "Control.mean"
names(ds.Agg)[names(ds.Agg)=="Target.OD"] <- "Target.mean"

# Calculate initial ratio between the target and the control
# This is the value that represents each biological sample
ds.Agg$Ratio <- ds.Agg$Target.mean / ds.Agg$Control.mean 

# Calculate the group means and normal sd (no propagation)
ds.group <- aggregate(Ratio ~ Group, data = ds.Agg, mean)
ds.group$sd <- aggregate(Ratio ~ Group, data = ds.Agg, sd)$Ratio
ds.group$sd.rel <- ds.group$sd / ds.group$Ratio * 100

# Print results for classical way of doing this (no propagation)
format(ds.group, digits=3)

  Group Ratio     sd sd.rel
1     1  0.07 0.0742  106.0
2     2  1.28 0.4080   31.8
```

A final read-out would be:

```
library(ggplot2) # version 0.9.0   

png(type = "windows", file = "c:/temp/propagation1.png",width=140,height=200)
ggplot(ds.group, mapping = aes(x = factor(Group), y = Ratio)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.8, position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = Ratio - sd, ymax = Ratio + sd), 
                width = 0.40, position=position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  scale_x_discrete("Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1, 1.7)) +
  theme_bw()
message(dev.off())
```

[image: No propagation]

Then an attempt on propagation:

```
# Calculate sd for technical duplicates which will be propagated
sdTmp <- aggregate(cbind(Control.OD, Target.OD) ~ Sample + Group, data=ds, sd) 
ds.Agg$Control.sd <- sdTmp$Control.OD
ds.Agg$Target.sd <- sdTmp$Target.OD

# Calculate the relative propagated sd associated with the calculated Ratio
fltRelativeSd <- with(ds.Agg, 
    sqrt( (Control.sd / Control.mean)^2 + (Target.sd / Target.mean)^2 ) 
)
ds.Agg$Ratio.sd <- ds.Agg$Ratio * fltRelativeSd
ds.Agg$Ratio.sd.rel <- ds.Agg$Ratio.sd / ds.Agg$Ratio * 100
```

**The follow code is my biggest concern when it comes to calculation of the propagated standard deviation:**

```
# Calculate propagated sd for the groups
ds.group$sd.prop <- aggregate(Ratio.sd ~ Group, data = ds.Agg, 
 function(x) { 
  sqrt( sum((x)^2) ) / length(x);
 })$Ratio
```

**to here.**

```
ds.group$sd.prop.rel <- ds.group$sd.prop / ds.group$Ratio * 100
```

Re-print the results with the propagated standard deviations:

```
format(ds.group, digits=3)

  Group Ratio     sd sd.rel sd.prop sd.prop.rel
1     1  0.07 0.0742  106.0  0.0111       15.79
2     2  1.28 0.4080   31.8  0.0418        3.26
```

And a graph:

```
png(type = "windows", file = "c:/temp/propagation2.png",width=140,height=200)
ggplot(ds.group, mapping = aes(x = factor(Group), y = Ratio)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.8, position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = Ratio - sd.prop, ymax = Ratio + sd.prop), 
                width = 0.40, position=position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  scale_x_discrete("Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1, 1.7)) +
  theme_bw()
message(dev.off())
```

So a read-out for the propagation:

[image: With propagation]

I would have expected standard deviations in the same neighborhood as seen on the first graph, however they seem a factor 10 off.

So my thoughts/questions at this point:

1. Am I doing the calculations right?
2. Does it make sense to do this calculation (it seems that the biological variance is ignored and only the initial duplicate sd is actually propagated and presented)?

Any comments are most welcome.

Additional info: The experiment uses a technique called [Western Blotting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_blot) and the image analysis was done in ImageJ in a similar fashion as described [here](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2010/11/analyzing-gels-and-western-blots-with-image-j/).

Comment: A lot of code to churn through in a few minutes. Care to pinpoint out your problem where you think it goes wrong?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik If there is an error in my calculations, I would think it to be in the code: `ds.group$sd.prop <- aggregate(Ratio.sd ~ Group, data = ds.Agg, function(x) { sqrt( sum((x)^2) ) / length(x);})$Ratio` But I am certainly not sure.